# Entity Framework Core 5 and CosmosDB SQL API - Include extension method does not work

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have followed the steps from the following EF Core 5 site in order to store and read items from the CosmosDB. Here is the site: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/database-providers/cosmos

Storing works as expected, but when running the command from the tutorial to read items, I'm getting following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Including navigation 'Navigation: Author.Books (List) Collection ToDependent Book Inverse: Author' is not supported as the navigation is not embedded in same resource.'

The line of code which throws the exception:

```
var list = context.Authors
    .Include(a => a.Books)
    .ToList();
```

It seems that Include method is not supported in EF Core 5 for CosmosDB. Does anyone have some experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was removing the separate `DbSet` in the context class, e.g. `DbSet<Book>`. With its own `DbSet`, my objects were being mapped to separate documents; without it, they're stored inside an array in the containing document (e.g. `Author`).

I imagine you want to query books based on other things besides their authors, but in my case I think I'll be able to work with it.

Answer (score -1):

I would take a look at the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos instead.

As it provides a means to map the Authors to Books

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
       modelBuilder.Entity<Authors>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Books);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/planetary-docs-sample
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: It's not an answer for the question.